# Checking for string in os.system response

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm running the following command in python to get a response for the printer status:

```
import os

printer_status = str(os.system('lpstat -p HP'))
```

When I run this code, it gives me a reponse regardless of whether I print the output or not. An example of the response it gives is:

```
printer HP is idle.  enabled since Mon 05 Jul 2021 15:17:02 BST
```

Is there a way in python for me to check if the sentence HP is idle exists in the return result? Because i'm looking to see if printer is idle before it sends a next job.

**UPDATE**

I've tried this but this doesn't work. It returns as Not Idle even though it's idle:

```
if "is idle." in printer_status:
    print("Idle")
else:
    print("Not Idle")
```

Comment: Can you please provide the response as a valid Python literal? ``print(repr(printer_status))`` should do.

Comment: From the docs of ``os.system:``: "If command generates any output, it will be sent to the interpreter standard output stream." and "On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process". In other words, `os.system` does *not* give you the output of the program, but merely shows it on the terminal. You might want to use ``subprocess`` instead to capture the output.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi  print(repr(printer_status)) returns '0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) will return the exit code of the command, not its output. What you are looking for is [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> result = subprocess.check_output(["lpstat", "-p", "HP"])

>>> print(result)
b'printer HP is idle.  enabled since Mon 05 Jul 2021 15:17:02 BST\n'

>>> b"is idle" in result
>>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `subprocess` and regex:

```
import subprocess, re

printer_status = subprocess.getoutput('lpstat -p HP')

is_printer_idle = len(re.findall("printer .* is idle", printer_status)) > 0
```

Comment: You can complement your answer putting a documentation link to `subprocess` package and showing what would be the final output of your answer.